# Ответы бота Вк в беседах (callback api python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, callback

У меня есть бот для ВК на callback api(python), в ЛС он отвечает, а вот в беседы нет!

```
            import vk
import random

session = vk.Session()
api = vk.API(session, v=5.0)


def get_random_wall_picture(group_id, token):
    max_num = api.photos.get(owner_id=group_id, album_id='260175787', count=0, access_token=token)['count']
    num = random.randint(1, max_num)
    photo = api.photos.get(owner_id=str(group_id), album_id='260175787ll', count=1, offset=num, access_token=token)['items'][0]['id']
    attachment = 'photo' + str(group_id) + '_' + str(photo)
    return attachment


def send_message(user_id, token, message, attachment=""):
    api.messages.send(access_token=token, user_id=str(user_id), message=message, attachment=attachment)
```

```
            import vkapi
import os
import importlib
from command_system import command_list

def damerau_levenshtein_distance(s1, s2):
   d = {}
   lenstr1 = len(s1)
   lenstr2 = len(s2)
   for i in range(-1, lenstr1 + 1):
       d[(i, -1)] = i + 1
   for j in range(-1, lenstr2 + 1):
       d[(-1, j)] = j + 1
   for i in range(lenstr1):
       for j in range(lenstr2):
           if s1[i] == s2[j]:
               cost = 0
           else:
               cost = 1
           d[(i, j)] = min(
               d[(i - 1, j)] + 1,  # deletion
               d[(i, j - 1)] + 1,  # insertion
               d[(i - 1, j - 1)] + cost,  # substitution
           )
           if i and j and s1[i] == s2[j - 1] and s1[i - 1] == s2[j]:
               d[(i, j)] = min(d[(i, j)], d[i - 2, j - 2] + cost)  # transposition
   return d[lenstr1 - 1, lenstr2 - 1]


def load_modules():
   files = os.listdir("mysite/commands")
   modules = filter(lambda x: x.endswith('.py'), files)
   for m in modules:
       importlib.import_module("commands." + m[0:-3])


def get_answer(body):
   message = "Прости, не понимаю тебя. ПЛАКИЧ! Напиши '?команды', чтобы узнать как не странно мои команды НЯ"
   attachment = ''
   distance = len(body)
   command = None
   key = ''
   for c in command_list:
       for k in c.keys:
           d = damerau_levenshtein_distance(body, k)
           if d < distance:
               distance = d
               command = c
               key = k
               if distance == 0:
                   message, attachment = c.process()
                   return message, attachment
   if distance < len(body)*0.4:
       message, attachment = command.process()
       message = 'Я поняла твой запрос как "%s"\n\n' % key + message
   return message, attachment


def create_answer(data, token):
   load_modules()
   user_id = data['user_id']
   message, attachment = get_answer(data['body'].lower())
   vkapi.send_message(user_id, token, message, attachment)
```

Comment: Зачем извиняться, если можно скопировать код в вопрос?

Comment: Вот исправил, вместо скринов код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отправка сообщений в беседы происходит почти так же, как в лс, только в api.messages.send вместо аргумента `user_id` нужно использовать `chat_id`

https://vk.com/dev/messages.send

Comment: А в конце где функция create_answer, нужно?

Comment: По приведённому куску кода не очень понятно, как вы хотите использовать create_answer, и откуда в него приходит параметр data. Но скорее всего - да, нужно.